# Marklogic don't save XML with format date incorrect

Tags: xml, marklogic, marklogic-8

I'm trying to save some XML(UBL) documents into Marklogic 8 with date formatting incorrect like this:

```
<cbc:IssueDate>2017-06-32</cbc:IssueDate>
```

I'm using Java API to save it but can't save because of the next exception:

> Server Message: XDMP-RANGEINDEX: Range index error: date fn:doc("/pe/sunat/document/97ed960e-a34a-4a5b-b070-fad3594445be")/*:SummaryDocuments/*:**IssueDate: XDMP-LEXVAL: Invalid lexical value "2017-06-32"**

I know that the format date is not correct but I still so want to save it. Is it possible save this XML? (I'm using the object `com.marklogic.client.document.DocumentWriteSet` to save lots of documents in a transaction)

Comment: I'm so sorry, I didn't know that Marklogic had range index for dates, I disable ranges index for dates and it can save that XML correctly.

Comment: You don't have to disable the range index completely. You could change the "invalid values" setting from "reject" to "ignore". It would allow you to ingest that document, but that value would not be indexed as a date, rather than getting rid of the index entirely. https://docs.marklogic.com/admin-help/range-element-index

Comment: Thanks @MadsHansen.

Comment: @MadsHansen, please make your response an answer so that we can upvote it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the "**invalid values**" setting from "**reject**" to "**ignore**". That would allow you to ingest that document, but that invalid date value would not be indexed. You would then be able to correct the formatting for the date values with post-processing.

http://docs.marklogic.com/admin-help/range-element-index

> - **invalid values**  specifies whether server should allow insertion of
>     documents that contain XML elements or JSON properties on which range
>     index is configured and their contents cannot be coerced to the index
>     data type. It can be configured to either **ignore** or **reject**. By default
>     server rejects insertion of such documents. However, if a user
>     configures **invalid values**  to **ignore**, these documents can be inserted.
>     This setting does not change the behavior of queries on invalid values
>     after documents are inserted in the database. Performing an operation
>     on an invalid value at query time can still result in an error.

Comment: "but that invalid date value would not be indexed" --> It means that I would have any error?. In this case how can I know which documents have error in date format? If I want to do queries with date, then could have any error?